# Abrir explorador de archivos desde un webForm de aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Quiero abrir el explorador de archivos desde un webForm de aspx para seleccionar un archivo pdf y establecer su ruta en una caja de texto y realizar una insert a una tabla que almacene la ruta del archivo.

Comment: No se puede. Puedes seleccionar un archivo, puedes subir el archivo, pero no puedes obtener la ruta del archivo del cliente para enviarla al servidor

Comment: @Yussef Como podria abrir el explorador de archivos y seleccionar el archivo para subirlo?

Comment: Con un input file --> `<input type="file" >` Mas info en https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<div>
    Select File 
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click"/>
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
    if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            //Este es el archivo seleccionado, use esta variable para obtener el path                
            FileUploader.PostedFile
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, con el fileUploader si que he conseguido abrir el explorador de archivos y elegir un documento

Comment: ¡Olvídalo! Si mi respuesta resolvió su problema, ¿puede seleccionarla como correcta?